# How to change serializer field name when validation error is triggered

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-validation

I need to change the view of the error displayed when I validate the field.

**serializer.py**

```
class ElementCommonInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    self_description = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True,
                                             validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z0-9,.!? -/*()]*$',
                                                                        message='The system detected that the data is not in English. '
                                                                                'Please correct the error and try again.')]
                                             )
    ....

    class Meta:
        model = Elements
        fields = ('self_description',......)
```

This error is displayed

```
{
    "self_description": [
        "The system detected that the data is not in English. Please correct the error and try again."
    ]
}
```

The key of error dict is field name - `self_description`. For FE I need to send another format like:

```
{
    "general_errors": [
        "The system detected that the data is not in English. Please correct the error and try again."
    ]
}
```

How to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way this could be achieved is via [custom exception handler](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

```
from copy import deepcopy
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def genelalizing_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Now add the HTTP status code to the response.
    if 'self_description' in response.data:
        data = deepcopy(response.data)
        general_errors = data.pop('self_description')
        data['general_errors'] = general_errors
        response.data = data

    return response
```

in settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils. genelalizing_exception_handler'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to rewrite the validate method.

```
def validate(self, data):
    self_description = str((data['self_description']))
    analyst_notes = str((data['analyst_notes']))
    if re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9,.!? -/*()]*$', self_description) or re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9,.!? -/*()]*$', analyst_notes):
        raise serializers.ValidationError({
                "general_errors": [
                    "The system detected that the data is not in English. Please correct the error and try again."
                ]
            })
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple.

you can rename the key field by using serializer method (source attribute)
below you can find an example code.

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    question_importance = serializers.IntegerField(source='importance')
    question_importance = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = create_question
        fields = ('id','question_importance','complexity','active')
```

Above you can see I have an importance field which is present in django model But here I renamed this field to question_importance by using source attribute . 
In your case it will be like below,

```
class ElementCommonInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    

    general_errors   = serializer.CharField(source="self_description")  
    general_error    =    serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True,
                                           validators=[])    
    class Meta:
         model = Elements
         fields = ('general_error',......)
```

Comment: Changing the field name itself is not quite acceptable, as there is a lot of other logic associated with it.

Comment: @jekson Thanks for your comment.